# Chamar um metodo toda vez que um Controller for acionado asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Em meu projeto tenho um método que cria um menu na pagina de layout *"_Layout.cshtml"*, por exemplo, no meu controle `HomeController.cs` fica esse método, e na `ActionResult Index()` chamo esse método, só que tenho varias outras `ActionResult` que chama outras *Views*, pagina de detalhes etc.. Eu tenho que chamar este método de criar o menu em todas as `ActionResult`? não tem uma forma de toda vez que o `HomeController` for acionado, independente da `ActionResult`, eu possa chamar este método de criar os menus? como se fosse um Page_Load?

Ex:

no meu _Layout.cshtml tenho o seguinte:

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-top-links list-unstyled">
   @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Menu)
</ul>
```

no meu "HomeController.cs" tenho o seguinte

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  MontaMenuPrincipal();
  return View();
}

public ActionResult OutroMetodo()
{
  MontaMenuPrincipal();
  return View();
}

public ActionResult OutroMetodo2()
{
  MontaMenuPrincipal();
  return View();
}

public void MontaMenuPrincipal()
{
   ViewBag.Menu = "html com o menu";
}
```

Minha dúvida é, tenho que chamar o método `MontaMenuPrincipal()` em todas as `ActionResult`? ou tem alguma forma de chamar esse método para todas as `ActionResult` desse Controller? sem ter que repetir ele? isso também serviria para outros métodos que seriam comuns para todas as `ActionResult`.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro o que está tentando fazer, mas pelo que entendi, na sua página `layout` está sendo chamado alguma `action`, você pode fazer da seguinte forma

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-top-links list-unstyled">
    @Html.Action("MontaMenuPrincipal", "Home");
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult OutroMetodo()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult OutroMetodo2()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult MontaMenuPrincipal()
{
   ViewBag.Menu = "html com o menu";

   return PartialView("_Menu");
}
```

Crie uma `PartialView` com nome "_Menu"

**PartialView _Menu:**

```
<div>
   @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Menu)
</div>
```

**Outras views:**

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```

**Explicação:**

Na `view` `layout` é adicionado o `@Html.Action` que toda vez irá carregar o código do `controller` **home** e da `action` **MontaMenuPrincipal**. No `controller` foi alterado para retornar uma `PartialView` e a `ViewBag` e, por fim, na `PartialView` criada, é feito o `raw` dessa `ViewBag`

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, Ducke.

A arquivo **_Layout.cshtml**, é aonde fica o Layout padrão para suas views. Quando você cria um projeto no Visual Studio do tipo Asp.Net MVC, ele cria automaticamente esse arquivo. Geralmente, nele contém a barra de navegação que fica na parte de cima da página, com um alguns links como, Home, About e Contact.

Para que todas as suas Views herdem esse layout contido no **_Layout.cshtml** automaticamente, você deve verificar se o arquivo ***ViewStart.cshtml*** ( que tica dentro da pasta Views do seu projeto) está dessa forma:

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```

Caso esteja, tudo que estiver no **_Layout.cshtml** será aplicado para todas as suas views, sem necessidade de você repetir código.

Se for possível, tenta colocar esse menu no **_Layout.cshtml**, para compartilhar para todas as suas views.

Caso não resolva, posta aqui a HomeController pra gente dar uma olhada. :D

Comment: Felipe, essa parte eu entendi bem, editei minha dúvida pra ver se fica mais claro, e muito obrigado pelo help!